# Yarn start takes a long time in my React app

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

When I run my React application first time, it takes more than 30 minutes.

Is there any way to speed up Yarn installation and start time?

Comment: what command are you running? The delay might be somewhere else, and not because of yarn.

Comment: I use yarn install and yarn start

Comment: 30 minutes to installing or running the app?

Comment: "Creating an optimized production build..." waiting long time with this

Answer (score 0):

updated `ts-node`  package  to the latest version `10.0.0` and now it is so speed (< 1 minuetes)

cheers !!